# How can I apply and drop my latest git stash in the same command?

Tags: git

It appears that when I do git stash apply, I need to then type in git stash drop in order to remove that stash from the available stashes.  Can I do this in one command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git stash pop` is what you're looking for. As the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) says:

```
pop [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]

    Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on
    top of the current working tree state, i.e., do the inverse operation
    of git stash save. The working directory must match the index.

    Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not
    removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand
    and call git stash drop manually afterwards.
```

Comment: Note that if a merge conflict results, you still have to manually `drop` the stash after resolving the conflict.